# C++ CLI string processing from serial port

Tags: c++-cli

windows 7, msvs2010, C++ CLI

I want to save last 50 chars into a file  from *data* received from serial port. Normally, to receive all data I would do this:

```
  //Reading all exsisting data in serialport buffer
  String^ data = _serialPort->ReadExisting();        
  sw->Write(data);  
  delete (IDisposable^)sw;
```

What should I do if I want to save only last, say, 50 char?

Comment: @Inisheer Thanks for editing my question.

Comment: `sw->Write(data->Substring(Math::Max(0, data->Length - 50)));`

Comment: Note: Since you've chosen to use .NET's strings, be sure of three things: you are reading using the device's character encoding, you are writing using the desired encoding (say, UTF-8), you are counting full Unicode codepoints-not UTF-16 code units which could result in splitting a codepoint because a codepoint can take either one or two code units to encode.